# Is it common in any other first world countries besides the US to work while attending university?

Tags: united-states, work-life-balance

I have an old family friend in Japan (born and raised). We were recently talking about academics as he is in his 2nd year of Uni and I have 1 B.S and soon to have another with the goal of moving on to a Masters this fall.

While talking he asked if I "Work or study" as he knew I completed my first degree but was unaware I started my second. When I mentioned that I both go to Uni and work a corporate job in my industry he was, no joke, speechless.

He couldn't believe someone could both attend a Uni and work at the same time without failing classes. He told me that people only work part time jobs very sparingly during school semesters and then work more during the summer but can't even begin to believe working in a corporate job while still studying.

I don't know too many people that attend my Uni and don't either have 2 part-time jobs or a full time jobs (except for those with free rides or very generous parents).

Many people I know from other countries (I try to culture myself) ask me the same question "Do you work or study?" and they get very confused when I tell them "both" and explain my situation.

Is this only common in the US? I've talked to people from Singapore, Japan, Canada, Greece, and the UK and they all can't believe working and going to Uni at the same time.

Comment: If you have a 9-5 job, when are you are attending classes since classes are usually in the morning?

Comment: My work hours are generally 2-whenever I'm done (8-10pm). I do a lot of analytical work for that day based on properties my company owns residential and commercial so the full results for each day aren't available until 4ish. This makes going to morning classes easy. I also take a couple online courses.

Comment: _Is this only common in the US?_ — I don't think this is common even in the US.

Comment: @JeffE it may not be but from my experiences most students need to both work and study because loan rates are sky high so at the end of each semester most my friends and I compare costs to cover which range from $2,000-$5,000

Comment: Then you do not have a full time job. In Greece, it is common for students especially in the STEM field to have part-time jobs (private tutoring, building websites etc). Also, getting a second degree is easier than getting your first (you have already learnt how to study more efficiently).

Comment: Many of us work(ed) only part-time, relying on scholarships, loans, and family to make up the difference. Probably most. There were some who took Memj's approach but not many. And I was at one of the most expensive schools in the country -- albeit one with true need-blind admission; if you could get in, they'd work with you to get it paid.

Comment: (I'm tempted to vote to close for false premise, but I don't have any more hard stats than the OP does.)

Comment: I have edited the title of the post to match the specific question asked in the body. (Specific, objective titles are highly preferred over non-specific, provocative titles here.)

Comment: @Alexandros what do you mean "Then you do not have a full time job"? I work between 40-50 hours a week (depending on work load). In the US 40 hours a week is commonly referred to as "full time"

Comment: I said I go in around 2 and work until done which can be usually 8-10 pm meaning 6-8 hours a day 6 days a week. Then factor in days I stay late.

Comment: I think the question "What percentage of US college/university students also work a full-time job?" is already an interesting one.  If by this one means students who are enrolled full time in a BA/BS program at a 4 year college or university, I would expect it to be about 1%.  I think we should nail this down before we compare to other countries.  I also think "It seems that I need a full-time job to attend this school" would be a useful thing to mention to a financial aid officer.

Comment: Most full time jobs has not such a flexibility, nor in the US or else, so I don't think many does this way, in whatever "first world country". Also, most people is busy with their first degree, meaning they can only do unqualified/low paying jobs. Also, I seriously question a worth of any degree that someone gets doing a 40+ hours workweek, as it means that you can commit less then 30-40 hours to study (including commuting and all other stuff).

Comment: My impression was that *fewer* people worked besides their studies in the U.S. than in the European countries I know because of the loan culture (and lower average living costs).

Comment: Many people (including myself) worked full-time while enrolled full-time at my undergrad. It seemed very common. In fact, over 24% were full-time students in the military.

Comment: I can answer as to why this is incomprehensible in Japan, but that doesn't appear to be the question you asked.

Comment: While I know Brazil doesn't classify as developed, just FYI, by law, 40% of all undergrad offerings must be at night (7-11pm), to allow full time work. Some engineering courses take 7 years this way (3600h-4200h). Not an easy thing to accomplish...

Comment: I am currently in Japan, and the vast majority of the students I know (bsc. and master level) have part-time jobs, including during the semester. I'm surprised your friend is surprised!
Back in Switzerland, it wasn't uncommon to have part-time jobs, but not super common either. It depends a lot however what you study (I was in STEM. My friends in humanities tended to work more often I think, though this is completely just a personal impression.)

Answer (score 5):

In Germany, at least one survey reports that [47 percent of students work during the semester, and 63 percent work during the holidays between semester.](http://de.statista.com/statistik/daten/studie/201632/umfrage/umfrage-zum-parallelen-arbeiten-neben-dem-studium/)

Most of these students earn less [than 500 Euros a month](http://de.statista.com/statistik/daten/studie/190637/umfrage/monatlicher-netto-verdienst-von-studenten-in-deutschland/), but 6 percent earn more than 1000€ after taxes. Over [60 percent that have jobs have one to finance their studies/living expenses.](http://de.statista.com/statistik/daten/studie/190651/umfrage/gruende-fuer-die-arbeit-neben-dem-studium/) For [7 percent of students, their job is their only source of income](http://de.statista.com/statistik/daten/studie/37869/umfrage/finanzierungsart-vom-studium-im-jahr-2009/).

According to the [Sozialerhebung 2012](http://www.sozialerhebung.de/download/20/Soz20_11_Kap09.pdf) (a large survey by a federal agency)  figure 9.10, 13 percent of students studying towards their first degree  worked more than 20 hours a week on average in 2012. Whether that's "common" is a matter of interpretation.

The part on [financing](http://www.sozialerhebung.de/download/20/Soz20_08_Kap06.pdf) reports a median income of 300€ from working, with 63 percent of students doing some kind of work. Figure 6.5 shows that 2 percent of students only finance through studies through work, with an average income of 960 Euro, and 13 percent mainly finance their life through working, with an average income of 660 Euros.

(All sources in German)

Comment: I have no idea about the quality of those statistics, but I like seeing an answer that has some.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy thank you! The Sozialerhebung, at least, is done by the "Deutsches Zentrum für Hochschul- und Wissenschaftsforschung" the German Centre of Higher Education  and Science Research (loose translation), a federal agency and should be pretty reliable.

Answer (score 4):

Many colleges in Taiwan have evening divisions. They offer evening programs for the students who have full time jobs in the daytime.

For example, [College of Management of China University of Technology](http://www.cute.edu.tw/en/dep11.htm)

> has set up a daytime program in the four-year college division and an evening program in the extension division.

Usually their evening program will take 5 years for the students to get their bachelor degrees. This is because the evening division students really don't have much time to take classes in the evenings.

Working full time in the day and go to school in the evening is not uncommon in Taiwan. I personally have many friends who received their Bachelors degree from evening divisions of universities.

Answer (score 3):

I am from Portugal and I'm finishing this year my Computer Engineering graduation. I've been working fulltime since I've started studing and here we have a thing called "student worker statute". This statute is very important on examination period were the employers must give two extrad days off per exam.
Here in Portugal there's a lot of people who works and study at the same time although it's more frequent they work in par-time.

Answer (score 3):

In Australia it certainly happens frequently. I know of a few people who have completed masters degrees while working full time in their fields. My former boss started and finished his MBA while running a department.

Answer (score 0):

My country is NZ .When I was at Uni in the 1980s it was normal for students to work over the holidays .In fact well over 90% did so including me .Now days the situation has changed and there is a new normal .I work with lots of students which they now call interns.It is normal for Uni students to work part time during thier studies and work over the holidays .In the 1980s it was normal for a postgrad student to have a research position but I was very lucky as a repeat student which technically means undergrad to have a position .Nowdays most postgrad students do not get any research position .These days most students employment is mainly in the service industry and therefore has little vocational relevence to compensate the low wages.

Answer (score -2):

I am from Germany, and here you are not even allowed to have a fultime-job while being a student

The reasoning is that you cannot work fultime and study fultime, so are only allowed to work 20 hours/week on average (fultime being 40 hours).

If you want or need to work more, you have to either find illegal work (as the word says, illegal) or enroll as a part-time student (at least with respect to some social security issues and such, which is mandatory in Germany)(which has all kinds of unwanted consequences on the level of taxes, social fees and so on).

Probably even more extreme then in Japan :D

Comment: Can you provide the source of this, please? I know plenty of people, who already started full-time work before they finished their studies (in Germany). Maybe things have changed?

Comment: And since the question was about if people work in other countries, while studying - are you suggesting this is not the case in Germany? I think plenty of people are working (yes, part time only), but I had been working alongside studying since my 4th semester and many people I know did the same. The university even encourages it and employ you themselves as tutors, etc.

Comment: I can provide plenty of German language sources, can you read them or have someone translate them to you? Might take a bit longer to find them in english.

Comment: I understood the question (and still understand it so, on second reading) this way: the authors Japanese friend says Japanese students work  if at all, parttime, which the author sees as opposed to his own case, where he works fulltime, which he does not deem unusual, so he wishes to know how common it is in other countries for a student to work fulltime. I am not denying that a lot of German students work parttime

Comment: yes, I can read them and Google Chrome usually does an "ok" job of translation for others

Comment: in any case - my point is - you are claiming this is "not even allowed". I really want to see the law referring to: as a student you can not work more than 40 hours. Also, what are you referring to in terms of "part-time" student? I have never seen such an option in Germany - you either enrol or you don't. More info: http://www.spiegel.de/unispiegel/studium/teilzeitstudenten-halb-studieren-aber-voll-bezahlen-a-454131.html

Comment: As you are obviously well able to understand a German article I might as well give you the German source which is here: http://www.studienfinanzierung.de/jobben/studentenstatus.html

Comment: Meaning you do not count as a student officially if you work more than that amount, so you have to pay health insurance, social insurance, retirement insurance and so on. And yes there are universities where you can be enrolled parttime officially, but there are few cases where that is important: for instance if there is a rule that you have to have such and such credits after a certain time, that time is usually longer for parttimers. However, for reasons of anonymity, I will not give you an example where you can enroll parttime as I am not mentioning my own university here.

Comment: Non of this means that you are **not allowed** to work full-time - you may have to pay for health care, etc, but you are allowed to work as much as you want. If you can collect the credits at the same time, nobody is going to expel you for the university ...

Comment: Exactly, you lose your "Studentenstatus" with respect to these insurances if you work more, it is in the SGB (Sozialgesetzbuch). http://www.freilaw.de/studentenstatus-und-nebenbeschaftigung/2169

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36890/discussion-between-chris-and-valjean).